# Cassandra Pagination Using Datastax driver 3.6: Null paging state and fetch size not honoured

Tags: java, android, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

We are trying to make an Application that returns paginated results from cassandra db for a UI.

UI would pass `fetchSize` and `pagingState` to our API and based on that we would return a `List<MyObject>` of `size=fetchSize`. If `pagingState` is passed we would resume the query from last page (as mentioned in cassandra docs : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/paging/)

Please note that I'm using Cassandra driver version 3.6.

But when we implemented this, Cassandra always returns all entries in the database ignoring the fetch size, which in turn results `null` value for `ResultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState()`. How do I solve this?

I created 16 records in my database for `MyObject` and tried passing fetch size as 5 to get them. All 16 records have same partition key `ID-1`.

```java
// Util method to invoke Statement. "session" is cassandra session 

public static ResultSet execute(int pageSize, Statement statement, String pageState) { 
    if (isVoid(pageSize)) {
        pageSize=-1;
    }
    statement.setFetchSize(pageSize);
    if (!isVoid(pageState)) {
        statement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pageState));
    }
    return session.execute(statement);
}

// Accesor interface method for my query that returns a Statement 
object

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + MY_TABLE + " WHERE id=:id")
Statement getAll(@Param("id") String id);

// Main Code returning list of MyObject that has an object Mapper -> 
//mapper 
Statement statement=accessor.getAll("ID1");
ResultSet rs=execute(5,statement,null );
List<MyObject> list=mapper.map(rs).all();
String pageState=rs.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
```

In the above code, I expected Cassandra to return a list of 5 `MyObject` objects and have a string value for my `pageState` variable.
Neither worked as expected.

List had a size of 16 (Basically it fetched all records)
and because of above, `pageState` was `null` as all records were already fetched.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: 
From observation `ResultSet` will honour fetchSize passed in the statement, but when we map it to `List<MyObject>` using `all()` method, it fetches all the results in the database(of size = Cluster wide fetchSize).
So when I invoked `Result#one` method 5(= `pageSize`) times and pushed them in a List, I got the paging state as well as results of size page size.

Sample Util method for above

```java
public static <T> List<T> getPaginatedList(ResultSet resultSet, Mapper<T> mapper,int pageSize) {
    List<T> entities=new ArrayList<>();
    Result<T> result=mapper.map(resultSet);
    IntStream.range(1,pageSize).forEach(i->{
        entities.add(result.one());
    });
    return entities;
}
```

What is the performance impact of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were able to discern, the reason you are getting all results back despite the fact that you are specifying `setFetchSize` is because fetch size simply sets the requested size of each requested page.  When you invoke `all()`, the driver transparently pages through all results.

Calling `one()` individually will not have a performance impact when compared to `all()`, however I would recommend changing your logic for consuming the page as I would expect `IntStream.range(1, pageSize)` to fail if you've exhausted your result set (i.e. you set fetch size to 500, but there are only 495 rows).  Instead you could use `IntStream.range(1, resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching())`.

You could also choose to iterate over the result set until `ResultSet.isExhausted()` returns true to prevent fetching the next page.

Comment: "getAvailableWithoutFetching()" ->
This will fetch count of fetch in the current Result Set (of size= pageSize) or will it fetch the count of entities of size = cluster wide fetch size?  
 If above is true, this will not fetch the count in linear (or worse) time ,right?

Comment: Internally it's calling .size() on an ArrayDeque which is a constant time operation (effectively O(1))